# TypeError: Cannot read property 'cache' of undefined - VueJS

Tags: vue.js, async-await

I created a Vue component which exports an async function. This component acts as a wrapper for calling my API. It's based on [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) with a [caching](https://github.com/RasCarlito/axios-cache-adapter) component that relies on [localforage](https://github.com/localForage/localForage) for some short lived persistence.

```js
import localforage from 'localforage'
import memoryDriver from 'localforage-memoryStorageDriver'
import { setup } from 'axios-cache-adapter'

export default {
    async cache() {
        // Register the custom `memoryDriver` to `localforage`
        await localforage.defineDriver(memoryDriver)

        // Create `localforage` instance
        const store = localforage.createInstance({
            // List of drivers used
            driver: [
                localforage.INDEXEDDB,
                localforage.LOCALSTORAGE,
                memoryDriver._driver
            ],
            // Prefix all storage keys to prevent conflicts
            name: 'tgi-cache'
        })

        // Create `axios` instance with pre-configured `axios-cache-adapter` using a `localforage` store
        return setup({
            // `axios` options
            baseURL: 'https://my.api',
            cache: {
                maxAge: 2 * 60 * 1000,          // set cache time to 2 minutes
                exclude: { query: false },      // cache requests with query parameters
                store                           // pass `localforage` store to `axios-cache-adapter`
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Here is how I am importing and using this component in my views:

```js
import api from '@/components/Api.vue'

export default {
    data() {
        return {
            userId: this.$route.params.id,
            userData: ''
        }
    },
    methods: {
        loadClient(userId) {
            const thisIns = this;
            api.cache().then(async (api) => {
                const response = await api.get('/client/find?id='+userId)
                thisIns.userData = response.data.data[0]
            }).catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error)
            })
        },
    },
    created() {
        this.loadClient(this.userId)
    },
}
```

I can import this component and everything appears to work. I get data back from my API. However, immediately after every call, I get an error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'cache' of undefined

Which references this line:

```js
api.cache().then(async (api) => {
```

I am unable to understand why this is happening, or what it means. The error itself indicates that the component I am importing is undefined, though that's clearly not the case; if it were, the API call would ultimately fail I would suspect. Instead, I am lead to believe that perhaps I am not constructing/exporting my async cache() function properly.

Comment: Put in some console logging or a `debugger` statement to confirm that `api` is not `undefined` and does have the expected `cache` method. If you're seeing the request go to the server then either `api.cache()` is being called fine or something else is making that request. When you say it references that line, does it specifically say that that line is causing the error or is it just one of the lines in the stack trace?

Comment: This should not be related, but... what is the reason behind making that api as a vue component? if you are not using it at all as a vue component, not even a mixin. This should be a plain js file and in the best case scenario I would convert it to a Vue plugin.
Other than that, [adapter docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios-cache-adapter#use-localforage-as-cache-store) exports the async function without wrapping it. Just give it a try exporting `export default async cache() ...`

Answer (score 1):

Upon further review, I don't actually understand why the [author has implemented](https://github.com/RasCarlito/axios-cache-adapter#use-localforage-as-cache-store) it the way he has. Why would you want to create an instance of localForage every single time you make an API call?

I've opted not to use a component and to only instantiate an instance of localForage once.

**main.js**

```js
import localforage from 'localforage'
import memoryDriver from 'localforage-memoryStorageDriver'
import { setup } from 'axios-cache-adapter'

// Register the custom `memoryDriver` to `localforage`
localforage.defineDriver(memoryDriver)

// Create `localforage` instance
const localforageStore = localforage.createInstance({
    // List of drivers used
    driver: [
        localforage.INDEXEDDB,
        localforage.LOCALSTORAGE,
        memoryDriver._driver
    ],
    // Prefix all storage keys to prevent conflicts
    name: 'my-cache'
})

Vue.prototype.$http = setup({
    baseURL: 'https://my.api',
    cache: {
        maxAge: 2 * 60 * 1000,          // set cache time to 2 minutes
        exclude: { query: false },      // cache requests with query parameters
        localforageStore                // pass `localforage` store to `axios-cache-adapter`
    }
})
```

**the view**

```js
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            userId: this.$route.params.id,
            userData: ''
        }
    },
    methods: {
        loadClient(userId) {
            const thisIns = this;
            thisIns.$http.get('/client/find?id='+userId)
                .then(async (response) => {
                    thisIns.userData = response.data.data[0]
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                    console.log(error)
                })
        },
    },
    created() {
        this.loadClient(this.userId)
    },
}
```